# How to unbrick ToToLink A950RG

Tags: wireless-router

My A950RG became bricked after updating the official firmware. I tried to ping it, but there was no response. The CPU light only flashed once after plugging in the power supply, and the power light remained on. How to debrick it?

Answer (score 1):

The only recovery method the manufacturer offers for this device is a factory reset. You can do this like so

STEP-1:
Press and hold the RST/WPS button for 10 seconds until the CPU led blinks quickly.
STEP-2:
After nearly 30 seconds, resetting is finished.

Source: https://www.totolink.net/data/upload/20181101/b9828f302ba2f959fd503cbc7d640de9.pdf?__K=3389cd91193686a588d28069a1c708d8e1678004021_317323210